# ml is like thisChange XML node name/Replace it with xml nodes (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Lets suppose that i have this xml node scheme:

```
<mat id="4230348">
       <home id="2339086"/><away id="2339218"/>
          <os/>
</mat>
```

How can I change the node `<os/>` into `<os></os>` because it causes a parsing issue?
When the xml is like this(contains info between tags, the parsing is ok:

```
<mat id="4230348">
       <home id="2339086"/><away id="2339218"/>
          <os> <a> <b> </b </a> </os>
</mat>
```

it reads the   stuff...
and if there is a node somewhere else which is like this:

```
<mat id="4230348">
           <home id="2339086"/><away id="2339218"/>
              <os/>
    </mat>
```

it fails to read the rest of the xml file

Comment: I'm not clear "where" you want to make this change.  The XML source file is a text file, and you can edit it accordingly.  You don't specify what the "parsing issue" is, but perhaps you wish to be able to input the XML source into a DOM object and manipulate it there?

Comment: Do you need to validate the input file and remove/fix corrupted node to go on with parsing?

Comment: the xml as is now, is valid, but I cannot parse it with XmlNode approach or HtmlNode in HtmlAgilityPack. I just want to change the xml node <os/> into <os></os>...just change the string <os/> to <os></os> if xml is handled as atxt file

Comment: XML is a text file and you can modify it with any text editor like notepad.

Comment: What parsing issues does it cause? Because <oss/> and <oss></oss> are semantically equal and should not cause parsing issues. I think the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: when it is like this: <oss></oss> it contains info inside these tags...when it is plain <oss/> it does not contain anything. That causes xml parsing to avoid reading the rest of the xml after this node(<oss/>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try XML Linq.  With Linq you can cast an element to a string so you won't get an exception if the item is null

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
            "<Root>" +
            "<mat id=\"4230348\">" +
               "<home id=\"2339086\"/><away id=\"2339218\"/>" +
               "<os/>" +
            "</mat>" +
            "<mat id=\"4230349\">" +
               "<home id=\"2339086\"/><away id=\"2339218\"/>" +
               "<os/>" +
            "</mat>" +
            "<mat id=\"4230350\">" +
               "<home id=\"2339086\"/><away id=\"2339218\"/>" +
               "<os>info</os>. " +
            "</mat>" +
            "<mat id=\"4230351\">" +
               "<home id=\"2339086\"/><away id=\"2339218\"/>" +
               "<os/>" +
            "</mat>" +            
            "</Root>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
            var results = doc.Descendants("mat")
               .Select(x => new {
                   matId = x.Attribute("id").Value,
                   homeId = x.Element("home").Attribute("id").Value,
                   awayId = x.Element("away").Attribute("id").Value,
                   os = (string)x.Element("os")
               })
            .ToList();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: There are multiple mat nodes in the xml. Some have <os/> and some others have <os>info</os>. When the prsing comes up  with <os/> it fails to read the rest of the xml.

Comment: Updated code. With Linq you can cast an element to a string so you won't get an exception if the item is null.  Wrapped code with Root so you will have only one root node.